# how to get type reference from value in json schema

Tags: jsonschema

I've got a json schema and I have 3 types of media, caption, image, and avatar.

Each of these media types has a different structure, so I'm using `$ref` and `oneOf` to specify which are valid options.

However, I can't figure out how to specify which ref to use based on a the value of a sibling.

My schema looks like this

```
const mediaSchema = {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["mediaType", "content", "points"],
    "properties":{
        "mediaType": {"type":"string", "pattern": "^(image|avatar|caption)$"},
        "content": {
            "oneOf": [
                {"$ref":"#/definitions/image"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/caption"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/avatar"}
            ],
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "caption": 
            {"type": "object",
                "required": ["text"],
                "properties": {
                    "text": {"type": "string"},
                    "fontSize": {"type": "string", "pattern": "^[0-9]{1,3}px$"}
            }
        },
        "image": {"type": "string", "format": "url"},
        "avatar": 
            {"type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {"type": "string"},
                    "image": {"type": "string", "format":"url"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when I define an avatar like

```
mediaItem = {
    "mediaType":"avatar",
    "content": {
         "name": "user name",
         "avatar": "https://urlToImage
     }
}
```

it should be valid, but if I define an avatar as

```
mediaItem = {
    "mediaType": "avatar",
    "content": "https://urlToImage"
}
```

it should throw an error as that is not valid for a media type of avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you should put the oneOf dispatcher to the root of the schema, and define the `"content"` with 3 separate constants as a discriminator, like this:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "mediaType": {
                    "const": "avatar"
                },
                "content": { "$ref": "#/definitions/avatar" }
            },
            "required": ["mediaType", "content"]
        },
        // ...
    ],
    "definitions": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: the `"const"` keyword exists only in the latest version of json schema (draft6). It may happen that the validator implementation you use doesn't support it yet. In that case you can replace `"const": "avatar"` with a single-element enum like `"enum": ["avatar"]`

Comment: that is working, but the error report is pretty bad. In my tests, I get `expected 'data.mediaType should be equal to constant, data.mediaType should be equal to constant, data.mediaType should be equal to constant, data should match exactly one schema in oneOf'` is there a nicer error output? Which suggests what the schema should be?

Comment: What json schema library do you use?

Comment: I'm using ajv, are you familiar with it? Probably a separate question, I thought errors would be standardized across libraries. https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv, I'll look into it there. Sorry to have bothered you with that question.